# Writing Unit Testing With Jasmine , Require JS in Karma for Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have Done a Library Management App with Angular JS and Mongo Lab will Act as a DB Part, I am facing issuse with Require JS Dependency While Crating Unit test Case

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lmaApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'lmaApp' is not available!
```

The Above error I am facing,kindly help me to get out from this.

**MyCode:**

**Controller.js**

```
define(
    ['modules'],
    function(lmaApp) {
        lmaApp.controller('gridControl',['$scope' , '$http' , 'internal' , 'commonValues', function($scope , $http , internalFn , commonValues){
            jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('ul.navbar-nav li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
            $('.loaderImg').removeClass('no-loading');
            var lmaTableData = internalFn.getTableData(commonValues.mongoAPIurl,commonValues.bookTableName,'');
                    var promise = lmaTableData
                    .success(function(tbData) {
                        if(tbData.length > 0){
                            $scope.nobook=0;
                            $scope.books =tbData;
                        }
                        else{
                           $scope.nobook =1; 
                        }
                    }).then(function (response) {$('.loaderImg').addClass('no-loading');});
        }]);
});
```

**modules.js**

```
define(
    ['app_config','angularRoute'],
    function() {
        var lmaApp =angular.module('lmaApp',['ngRoute'])
        return lmaApp;
    });
```

**app_config.js**

```
define(
    ['angular','angularRoute','modules'],
    function() {

            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['lmaApp'], {});
            });

    });
```

**My spec File**

**controllerSpec.js**

```
define(['angular', 'angular-mocks'], function() {
    describe('gridControl', function(){

      beforeEach(module('lmaApp'));

      it('should get the book table Datas', inject(function($controller) {
        var scope = {},
            ctrl = $controller('gridControl', {$scope:scope});

        expect(scope.phones.length).not.toEqual(0);
      }));

    });
});
```

Here i have a doubt with require js dependecy like i have to mention `modules.js` as a dependency in Spec file too.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller-spec.js is wrong, you need to call its dependencies which is your `module.js`, `app_config.js`, `Controller.js` also `'angularRoute'`. In other ot make your app to able to boostrap.

try it like this

```
define(['angular', 'angular-mocks','modules', 'app_config', 'Controller', 'angularRoute'], function() { ... }
```

Still I have nothing to be sure that it will work for you. Because if any of your configuration is wrong. It will be broken. Using requireJS with AngularJS in unit testing is very tricky/complex in the configuration.

You should read more about requireJS config, and using `shim` for define dependencies for your script. It will be lots clearer and eaiser to handle when your app getting bigger. For example you can do something like this in your config file:

```
shim: {
    'modules': ['angular', 'app_config', 'angular-mocks'],
    'app_config': ['angular', 'angularRoute', 'modules'],
    'Controller': ['modules']
}
```

and your controller-spec.js will be like this

```
define(['modules', 'app_config', 'Controller'], function(){ ... });
```

**Also** Bootstraping angular on element ready is not a good idea for testing. It may cause some conflict in loading simulating of karma. I am not sure but don't feel right about it

**Sencond** Your `app_config.js` and `modules.js` are dependency of each other. So what do you think if there's something require an order in loading. Which will need to load first? since Both required the other to be loaded before it got to be injeacted by requireJS.

**Still** I don't think my solution will work. Because your config seem so wrong.